# Gparted claims my internal drive is full

Tags: gparted

I intend to resize and add a new partition to my main drive, and for that purpose I have created a GParted-USB to resize my partition. However, this has proven to be more difficult than I thought, seeing as GParted claims that my internal drive is full.

[image]

Any idea as to what's causing this, and eventually how to fix it? (Ignore the key, I shot this from Fedora.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your drive is a LVM physical volume. Your free space is being managed by lvm. Look at `vgdisplay` to find free space in your volume group and `lvcreate` to create a new partition from that space.  To grow a partition you will first `lvextend` the logical volume then (if ext2/3/4) `resize2fs` to size the filesystem to the new volume size.

Comment: Thank you, some other sources are pointing in this correction as well, and it seems to be what I am looking for, thus, I will accept the answer, seeing as it is more than likely correct. However, could you link me to a guide that explains this in a beginner-friendly manner? Thank you.

Comment: This is a decent guide, just ignore the arch specific stuff. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LVM